# Error message list index out of range when it's not in Python

Tags: python

Why does the error message IndexError: list index out of range appear when the line that I am calling for is not out of range.

```
x = 3
f = open (testing.txt, "r")
UserInput = input("Please enter yes if you would like to view the name of the person. Else enter no.")
if UserInput = "yes":
    x = x+2
    Name = f.readlines(x)
    print (Name)
else:
    print ("Thanks for your help")
```

There is no reason that this should happen because there are over 20 lines in the file that i want to open but I can't print the 5th line.

Comment: This shouldn't produce the error message you're reporting, because Python should refuse to run it at all. There's a syntax error in the `if` condition. Please post code that actually produces the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

For condition checking purpose, you need to use double equal symbol.

```
if UserInput == "yes":
```

And also include the file-name inside quotes.

```
f = open('testing.txt', "r")
```

ie, you need to change your complete code to,

```
f = open ('testing.txtr', "r")
UserInput = input("Please enter yes if you would like to view the name of the person. Else enter no.")
x = 3
if UserInput == "yes":
    x = x+1
    Name = f.readlines()[x]
    print (Name)
else:
    print ("Thanks for your help")
```

And if you want to strip the newline character present in the `Name` variable, you need to use `strip()` function like `print (Name.strip())` .

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using `f.readlines(x)` correctly.

I think you want `f.readlines()[x]` (where `f.readlines()[0]` is the first line in the file)

Answer (score 0):

> f.readlines(x)

x is not line number but the sizehint (described below).

> If the optional sizehint argument is present, instead of reading up to EOF, whole lines totalling approximately sizehint bytes (possibly after rounding up to an internal buffer size) are read.
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines

You are looking for `f.readlines()[4]`